# Google maps doesn't show markers

Tags: json, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to build a webapp that uses Google Map api to show data from the server. It works fine but I need to refresh the page to populate the map with markers.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
latitude=1;
longitude=1;

var styles = [
    {
      stylers: [
        { hue: "#00ffe6" },
        { saturation: -20 }
      ]
    },{
      featureType: "road",
      elementType: "geometry",
      stylers: [
        { lightness: 100 },
        { visibility: "simplified" }
      ]
    },{
      featureType: "road",
      elementType: "labels",
      stylers: [
        { visibility: "off" }
      ]
    }
  ];



$(document).ready(function() {

if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
    latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({suppressMarkers: true});

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: coords,
        panControl: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        overviewMapControl: false,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
         styles: styles,
        navigationControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
        },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapContainer"), mapOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        var image = 'mapmarker.png';

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: coords,
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                title: "Your current location!"
        });

    });
}else {
    alert("Geolocation API is not supported in your browser.");
}


getLocations();


function getLocations() {
    $.getJSON("fromMyServer", function (json) {

        var location;
        $.each(json.key, function (i, item) {
            addMarker(item.lat,item.lng, item.name, item.address);

            var tiedot = item.Nimi;
        });

    });
}

var markersArray;


function addMarker(lat,lng,name,address) {

  var contentString = '<h3>'+name + '</h3>'+ address;

  var tiedot = contentString + '<br><button onclick="calcRoute('+lat+','+lng+')">get route</button> '

        var Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
            map: map,
            title:"Test"
        });


         google.maps.event.addListener(Marker, 'click', function() {
          $('.tiedot').empty();
          $('.tiedot').append('<p>'+tiedot+'</p>');
          $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
             //infowindow.open(map,this);

    });

}



});
function calcRoute(lat,lng) {

  var start = latitude+','+longitude;

  var end = lat+','+lng;
  var request = {
    origin:start,
    destination:end,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
    }
  });
}
```

The console shows that it gets the data from the server but for some reason it does not add any markers on the first page load. What could be the reason?

Comment: So does it add on the second page load?

Comment: Well it adds markers quite randomly. Sometimes I have to update the page 1 time, sometimes more to get the markers to the map...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
    getLocations();
});
```